# NuGet packages do not show after pushing to private NuGet Feed (NuGet.Server, IIS)

Tags: visual-studio, iis, nuget, nuget-server

I followed the instructions on [Hosting Your Own NuGet Feeds](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds):

1. Create an empty web application
2. Installed the `NuGet.Server` package
3. Set `~/Packages` as the `packagesPath` in Web.config
4. Set my API key in Web.config
5. Created the .nupkg file from a class library using `NuGet.exe`
6. Created a new Application in IIS called "NuGet"
7. Granted Read/Write access to the `IUSR` and `IIS_IUSRS` users and groups
8. Ran `nuget setApiKey ABC123 -Source http://localhost/NuGet` from the command line
9. Ran `nuget push Foo.Bar.dll.nupkg -Source http://localhost/NuGet`

The push to the NuGet server succeeded. I can view the folder in Windows Explorer and see the .nupkg file.

When I go to `http://localhost/NuGet/nuget/Packages` I get an RSS feed showing the package I just pushed.

When I go to `http://localhost/NuGet/nuget/` I get an empty list of packages:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<service xml:base="http://localhost/NuGet/nuget/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
  <workspace>
    <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
    <collection href="Packages">
      <atom:title>Packages</atom:title>
    </collection>
  </workspace>
</service>
```

After configuring NuGet in Visual Studio to include `http://localhost/NuGet` as one of the package sources, I can't install the package I just pushed either.

This is all running on:

- Windows 7
- IIS 7.5

**Why does the NuGet package show up in the RSS feed (`/NuGet/nuget/Packages`), but not through `/NuGet/nuget`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `/NuGet/nuget/Packages`is the URL where packages are listed (it just happens to be in RSS format because that was the original implementation decision), and `/NuGet/nuget` is the API endpoint used for package operations such as pushing, deleting, etc.

The XML you've posted isn't an empty list of packages, it's more of a service descriptor. An empty list of packages would be the result found at: `/NuGet/nuget/Packages()?$filter=1 eq 2`